# MK Map View - iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, dictionary, position

I know that by adding the map framework it should automatically add your iPhone's postion, but when i test it in the simulator, it doesn't work...

Is there any line of code I can add in my method which will allow me to see my position?

Answer (score 3):

Your questions is a little ambiguous.

That said, there are two things you should note. To determine your location, you need to use CoreLocation, not MapKit. Also, IIRC, if you use CoreLocation in the simulator it stays at the default "Cupertino".

Answer (score 1):

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```